# how to add HTML content to the blog post in confluence page from command line

Tags: python, html, macros, confluence

I am using RPC method storeBlogPost in python to create a blog post from on confluence page, I have successfully created the blog post but it is taking the content as raw string I want add a table to the blog page and it is taking the HTML and TABLE tags as regular text is there any way I can add HTML code to my blog post from command line

Comment: Please provide a code example

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve] for information about how to create excellent questions and how to prepare code examples.

Comment: self.newBlogPostData = {"title":self.name,"content":self.content,"space":self.spaceKey}
                        self.new_blog_post = self.server.confluence1.storeBlogEntry(self.token,self.newBlogPostData)

Comment: this is the function I am using storeBlogEntry which is present on the server side is I add a simple HTML code to print hello world in the content section, instead of printing hello world It will print whole html code in the blog post but I want the html code to be executed